# grep:how to use non-capturing group?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I am confused about the following command

```
$ cat num.txt  
1
2
3
1st
2nd
3th
$ cat num.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9](?:st|nd|th)?'
```

I think it should output as

```
1 
2 
3
1
2
3
```

But it output as

```
1
2
3
1
2nd
3th
```

What am I doing wrong here?Thanks for any help.

Comment: A non-capturing group doesn't prevent any substring to be in the whole match result. It only avoids to create a capture (a separate substring accessible with the group number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -Eo '^[0-9]+' file
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Or using **lookahead** in `grep -P`:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=st|nd|th)?' file
1
2
3
1
2
3
```